# Use of 'cum' as the interstitial in a three-word semi-comparative adjective?

Tags: etymology, compound-adjectives

I have occasionally encountered and often written a three-word adjective of the form 'X-cum-Y' to describe a person, where the X and Y are normally set somewhat in tension with one another, if they are not outright contradictory states. I've seen this device used to denote character development; for example, if a nominally-celibate priest is discovered to have taken a lover, they might be described as a 'priest-cum-philanderer'.

Of course, given the euphemistic use of 'cum', such usage as I describe above has become rare (if it ever was common to begin with), but I am curious about it, regardless.

What is the function of what I call "the interstitial 'cum'"? What is the history of its usage? Are there any rules or general guidelines for deploying it appropriately in prose?

I would be grateful for any information on the topic.

Comment: I think you mean [_cum_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cum), as in priest-_cum_-philanderer.

Comment: I agree that I meant 'cum', as noted above; I must have either transposed it with 'come' or read a few incorrect examples that stuck with me. In either case, this question is almost certainly a duplicate of the question linked to by @medica. Thank you for your answers!